# What to use instead of org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest?

Tags: java, jboss, resteasy

I just found that `org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest` is deprecated, invalidating everything I could find on Google about how to use the `RESTEasy` client. The [Javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0-beta-1/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/client/ClientRequest.html) gives no indication as to what to use instead. Google is likewise silent.

I have reverted to `2.3.5` for now, but would be interested in the answer anyways, as well as how one was supposed to find out the answer without asking someone else who knew - is there a resource with that information where I could have looked ?

Comment: #easyPeezey.  I'll add to your comments..that.... the examples seldom contain the import statements (<<this drives me nuts), and groupids and artifactids would also be very appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The 3.0 beta documentation [here](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0-beta-1/userguide/html_single/index.html#d4e2018) describes these deprecations like so:

> Resteasy manual client API, interceptors, StringConverters,
>   StringParamterConverters, and Async HTTP APIs have all been deprecated
>   and will be removed possibly in a later release. There is now a JAX-RS
>   2.0 equivalent for each of these things.

This would imply that the preferred method will be to use the JAX-RS Client API described in [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20121015171154/http://weblogs.java.net/blog/spericas/archive/2011/10/20/jax-rs-20-client-api-generic-interface)

Comment: There is also some useful information [buried in the Javadocs for `Invocation.Builder`](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.4.Final/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/client/Invocation.Builder.html) which doesn't refer to a non-existent `ClientFactory` class, but it would be great if the RestEasy authors added some pointers from the deprecated classes.

Answer (score 7):

If we assume there is a JSON API at `http://example.org/pizza/{id}.json`, (where 'id' is a pizza ID) which returns results such as

```
{ 
  "name": "Hawaiian",
  "toppings": ["tomato", "ham", "cheese", "pineapple"]
}
```

Building on the [`Invocation.Builder` Javadocs](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.4.Final/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/client/Invocation.Builder.html), we can do something like this,

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation;
import org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature;

public class PizzaClient {
    private Client client;

    public PizzaClient() {
         client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
         // enable POJO mapping using Jackson - see
         // https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#json.jackson
         client.register(JacksonFeature.class); 
    }

    /** POJO which maps to JSON results using Jackson */
    public static class Pizza {
        private String name;
        private String[] toppings;

        public String getName() { return name; }
        public String[] getToppings() { return toppings ; }
    }

    public Pizza getPizzaById(String id) {
        String uri = String.format("http://example.org/pizza/%s.json", id)
        Invocation.Builder bldr = client.target(uri).request("application/json");
        return bldr.get(Pizza.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       PizzaClient pc = new PizzaClient();
       Pizza pizza = pc.getPizzaById("1");
       System.out.println(pizza.getName() + ":");
       for (String topping : pizza.getToppings()) {
            System.out.println("\t" + topping);
       }
    }
}
```

(this is also assisted by [this post](http://guidogarcia.net/blog/2012/03/02/how-to-develop-java-rest-client/) although that uses the deprecated API).

Note also that you may need to register a special handler if you want to use Jackson to read POJOs (or, I think, using JAXB) as documented [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#json.jackson)

**Update**
You actually only need the following Maven dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

(In which case you're not using RestEasy at all -- the `javax.ws.rs` JAXRS implementation comes from Jersey)

**OR** you can stick with JBoss:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

In which case you can just remove the JacksonFeature line in the above code, and the code uses the more liberal Apache licence.

Answer (score 1):

The [RESTEasy documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.6.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#RESTEasy_Client_Framework) says we should close the client connection; that would be `client.close()` in your example.  But every example I can find does not do this.  Will the client connection get closed automatically during garbage collection?