# ClientRequestFactory RestEasy Deprecated... Any other RestEasy alternative ?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, resteasy, deprecated

I need to create rest-easy client, using de interface of the RestService created by others... 
That's work good, except by just one thing...

When i update from rest-easy 2.3.5.Final to rest-easy 3.0.x, the ClientRequestFactory class appear like @Deprecated.

The actual code is:

```
ClientRequestFactory crf = new ClientRequestFactory(UriBuilder.fromUri("http://url-of-service").build());
SomeRestInterface client = crf.createProxy(SomeRestInterface.class);
client.theMethod();
```

Any one, now what is the alternative of rest-easy for ClientRequestFactory at version 3.0.x?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to use instead of org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458450/what-to-use-instead-of-org-jboss-resteasy-client-clientrequest)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resteasy Client-API has been [marked deprecated](http://bill.burkecentral.com/2013/06/18/resteasy-3-0-final-released/) as JAX-RS standardized a Client-API.
You can find information about the Resteasy-integration of the new Client-API in the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.0.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html).

Your example could look like (untested):

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
Response response = client.target("http://url-of-service").request().get();
// read and close the response
```

Or if you want to use Resteasy Proxy Framework:

```
Client client = ClientFactory.newClient();
ResteasyWebTarget target = (ResteasyWebTarget) client.target("http://url-of-service");
SomeRestInterface client = target.proxy(SomeRestInterface.class);
client.theMethod();
```

Comment: I need to do the same thing but I cannot find ClientFactory, so from which jar do you use ClientFactory? Thank you! :)

Comment: Don't know if this class was renamed in between but it should be [ClientBuilder](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-rev-a/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.html) from the JAX-RS 2.0 API. Thanks for the hint, I updated the answer.

Comment: What will be the replacement of below two lines in 3.0.x version?
`ClientResponse<List<Student>> response = request.get(new GenericType<List<Student>>(){});
List<Student> students = response.getEntity();`

Comment: What does `request#get` return?

Comment: There is no request object now. I want to use latest API's old is not relevant now. I update my query here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36319394/what-should-we-use-for-clientresponse-and-generictype-in-latest-version-3-0-x please guide